# Jsoup changes output from single quote to double quote on HTML attributes

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsoup

We are using Jsoup to parse, manipulate and extend a html template. So far everything works fine until it comes to single quotes used in combination with HTML attributes

```
<span data-attr='JSON'></span>
```

That HTML snippet is converted to

```
<span data-attr="JSON"></span>
```

which will conflict with the inner json data which is specified as valid with double quotes only

```
{"param" : "value"} //valid
{'param' : 'value'} //invalid
```

so we need to force Jsoup to **NOT** change those single quotes to double quotes, but how? Currently that is our code to parse and produce html content.

```
pageTemplate = Jsoup.parse(new File(mainTemplateFilePath), "UTF-8");
pageTemplate.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);
pageTemplate.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8");

... adding some html 

pageTemplate.html(); // will output the double quoted attributes :(
```

Comment: This might be a bug in Jsoup's implementation.  You can report (or even better, discuss it with the developers) at http://jsoup.org/bugs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue here is. Can you provide an example of your final output, and an example of the output you would like to have instead?  Are you saying that you are ending up with `<span data-attr="{"param":"value"}"></span>` when you expect `<span data-attr='{"param":"value"}'></span>`?  If so, why do you not expect `<span data-attr="{&quot;param&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}"></span>`?

Comment: &quot; is not valid json, so what shall I do with that, or am I wrong? And yes the template before processing is `data-attr=''` and with the help of Jsoup I am adding Json between the single quotes. But once rendering and saving the resulting template I get `data-attr="{"data":"value"}"` but I expect `data-attr='{"data":"value"}'`

Comment: `&quot;` is valid HTML, though. If you have `<span data-attr="{&quot;param&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}"></span>` and you say `someSpan.getAttribute("data-attr")`, you don't get `&quot;` values, you get `"` values instead.  Can you HTML encode the Json value *before* putting it into the `data-attr` attribute? Doing so should replace your `"` values with `&quot;` values.

Comment: you were totally right, tried that and it works :)

Comment: please add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to HTML encode the JSON value *before* putting it into the `data-attr` attribute.  When you do so, you should end up with this:

```
<span data-attr="{&quot;param&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}"></span>
```

Although that looks fairly daunting, it is actually valid HTML.  When your corresponding JavaScript executes `someSpan.getAttribute("data-attr")`, the `&quot;` values will be transformed into `"` values automatically, giving you access to the original valid JSON string.