# Jsoup Parsing double quotes as &quot and single quotes as double quotes

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, double-quotes

I am trying to parse an HTML document. In the document, there is the 
        **span-data-personalization = '{"one":["two"]}'**  which converts to 
        **span-data-personalization = "{&quotone&quot:[&quottwo&quot]}"** while parsing. The double quotes convert to &quot and single quotes to double quote. I have also used doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false); with no success. Also, made the changes suggested in [jsoup - stop jsoup from making quotes into &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145426/jsoup-stop-jsoup-from-making-quotes-into-amp?rq=1)  It still did not work. And, I have also tried updating the Jsoup version.nothing seems to work. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jsoup changes output from single quote to double quote on HTML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630323/jsoup-changes-output-from-single-quote-to-double-quote-on-html-attributes)

Comment: encoding the json with html works, but when it's being parsed in the backend again, it changes the output and displays the encoded json on the front end. Which is what I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

The JSoup `Parser` class has a built in `unescapeEntities​` method. From the JSoup [documentation](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#unescapeEntities-java.lang.String-boolean-):

> public static String unescapeEntities​(String string,
>                                         boolean inAttribute)
>
> Utility method to unescape HTML entities from a string
>
> Parameters:
>
> **string** - HTML escaped string
>
> **inAttribute** - if the string is to be escaped in strict mode (as attributes are)
>
> Returns:
>   an unescaped string

Comment: Hello, Thank you. this method parses the string perfectly. But it stores it in a string. I need to store it in a doc. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: @ShashankS unfortunately I haven't found a method of having it escaped on the document object. This was the best I could find for if you need to select the value and do something with it.